# Py2exe - Can't run a .exe created on Windows 10 with a Windows 7 computer

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I created a .exe file using Py2exe on Windows 10 but when I try to run it on a Windows 7 computer it says that the os version is wrong.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? (like using another Python or Py2exe version or setting a specific configuration inside setup.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself and I'm going to share the answer if someone ever has the same mistake. I just had to download a 32-bit version of Canopy (with Python 2.7) and py2exe in order for them to work on Windows 7.